# kotlin - Room database error when unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, android-room

I am trying to write a unit test for my database, but I am getting the following error.
The error says that should not be a `null` value. 
Through the `Log.i`, I can know if variable `count` is a `null` value.
But I don't know why the variable `count` was worth `null`.

```
I/Junit: createDb
I/Junit: createAndRetriveNotes: count= null  3
I/Junit: closeDb

    ----- begin exception -----
E/TestRunner: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<null>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
        at com.riluq.notesapp.DatabaseTest.createAndRetriveDatabase(DatabaseTest.kt:47)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2090)
    ----- end exception -----

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<null>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.riluq.notesapp.DatabaseTest.createAndRetriveDatabase(DatabaseTest.kt:47)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2090)
```

I have checked my sql queries in NoteDao. kt, but it looks like the problem is not from there.

DatabaseTest.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import com.riluq.notesapp.database.AppDatabase
import com.riluq.notesapp.database.NoteDao
import com.riluq.notesapp.util.getNotes
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.junit.Assert.*

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class DatabaseTest {

    companion object{
        val TAG: String = "Junit"
    }

    private var mDb: AppDatabase? = null
    private var mDao: NoteDao? = null

    @Before
    fun createDb() {
        val context: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        mDb = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context,
            AppDatabase::class.java).build()
        Log.i(TAG, "createDb")
    }

    @After
    fun closeDb() {
        mDb?.close()
        Log.i(TAG, "closeDb")
    }

    @Test
    fun createAndRetriveDatabase() {
        mDao?.insertNoteAll(getNotes())
        val count: Int? = mDao?.getCount()
        Log.i(TAG, "createAndRetriveNotes: count= $count  " + getNotes().size )
        assertEquals(getNotes().size, count)
    }

}
```

AppDatabase.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.*

@Database(entities = [NoteEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun noteDao(): NoteDao

    companion object {
        val DATABASE_NAME: String = "AppDatabase.db"
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                            AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .build()
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }



    }


}
```

NoteDao.kt

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE

@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun insertNote(noteEntity: NoteEntity)

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun insertNoteAll(notes: List<NoteEntity>)

    @Delete
    fun deleteNote(noteEntity: NoteEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id = :id")
    fun getNoteById(id: Int): NoteEntity

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<NoteEntity>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM notes")
    fun deleteAll(): Int

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes")
    fun getCount(): Int


}
```

NoteEntity.kt

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.util.*

@Entity(tableName = "notes")
data class NoteEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int?,
    var date: Date?,
    var text: String
){
    constructor():this(null, null, "")
}
```

Why the variable `count` in `DatabaseTest.kt` value is `null`? and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `mDao` hasn't been initialized yet.
should've put `mDao = mDb.getNoteDao()` in `@Before` function